# $_REQUEST['action'] != 'foo' don't work in an if statement

Tags: php, if-statement, httprequest

I've following function:

```
public function output_berater(){
    if($_REQUEST["action"] != "berater_formular_suche" || $_REQUEST["action"] != "thema_formular_suche"){
        print_r($_REQUEST["action"]);           
    }
    return $output;
}
```

If I send a form with a hidden field `berater_formular_suche` or `thema_formular_suche` the `print_r` **shouldn't be** display on the screen.

I thought `!=` say '`if not`' ?!

Maybe there is some specials with `$_REQUEST` and if statements.

Can somebody explain me why my print_r is displaying?

Edit:

if I submit my form:

Output $_REQUEST

```
Array
(
    [action] => berater_formular_suche
    [berater] => klaus-testname
)
```

if I don't submit my form:

Output $_REQUEST

Empty array.

Comment: `print_r($_REQUEST)` and post its value

Comment: @Saty I edit my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use `&&` instead of `||`

```
 if($_REQUEST["action"] != "berater_formular_suche" && $_REQUEST["action"] != "thema_formular_suche"){
```

---

Optionally, you can load into array and then easily check:

```
$possible_values = ["berater_formular_suche","thema_formular_suche"];
if(!in_array($_REQUEST['action'],$possible_values)) { // Check if your posted values is not in array
     print_r($_REQUEST["action"]); 
}
```

Comment: The print_r is still displayed

Comment: Mh okay. I will test a bit. Thank you.

Comment: Yes it works. Sorry don't know where was my mistake.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use it like 
e.g.

```
public function output_berater(){
    global $_REQUEST;
    if($_REQUEST["action"] != "berater_formular_suche" || $_REQUEST["action"] != "thema_formular_suche"){
        print_r($_REQUEST["action"]);           
    }
    return $output;
}
```

Comment: I think thats it. Can you tell me where I can pass $_REQUEST in an add_shortcode of wordpress? add_shortcode('berater_ausgabe', array($this,'output_berater'));